# -webkit- animation browser compatibility

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, rollover

I've Been practicing some CSS By making some rollover buttons, and using `-webkit` but i heard that `-webkit` is only compatible with chrome and safari. So if i want to make the animations work on other browsers what code do i add? Here is my code:

Html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Rollover buttons</title>
</head>
<body>
    <article>   
        <p id="button">Button!</p>
    </article>
</body>
</html>


body{
    text-align:center;
}
#button{
    display:block;
    border:2px solid green;
    margin:150px 400px;
    background:#604085;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.5s,width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}
#button:hover{
    background:#67e456;
    width:110px;
    height:60px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transition: opacity 0.5s linear; /* vendorless fallback */
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear; /* opera */
-ms-transition: opacity 0.5s linear; /* IE 10 */
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear; /* Firefox */
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear; /*safari and chrome */
```

You want to have a read up on vendor prefixes. Here's an example for a simple opacity transition with comments.

Have a look here for up to date browser support - http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Thanks, Ill include this code and take a look at vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use image sprites for rollovers like so:

```
.button {
background-image: src(../images/soandso.jpg);
background-image: top left;
width: 45px;
height: 15px;
}

.button:hover {
background-image: src(../images/soandso.jpg);
background-image: bottom left;
width: 45px;
height: 15px;
}
```

then you can use jQuery for a fade in effect or whatever your trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee cross-browser compatibility it's best not to use CSS3 animations at all at this time, and instead use something like jQuery Effects to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

As @BoltClock pointed out, `-webkit` is a vendor prefix. However, there is a limited amount of [support from other vendors for animation](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) and I expect this will increase as animation is [receiving attention/formalization from the W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/).

Note that [transition](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/) (which your CSS shows) and animation (referenced by the title) are covered with a different set of prefixes and W3 documents.